# How to initialize AngularJS component with DIV tag attribute?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use just a custom attribute to instantiate component like this:

*index.html*

```
<div evaluation-paste></div>
```

Rest of the code:

*evaluation.paste.ts*

```
export const evaluationPasteComponent: angular.IComponentOptions = {
  template: require('./evaluation.paste.html'),
};
```

*evalutaion.paste.html*

```
<div class="row">
  paste component
</div>
```

*index.ts*

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import { EvaluationController } from './evaluation.controller';
import { evaluationPasteComponent } from './evaluation.paste';
import { evaluationParseComponent } from './evaluation.parse';
import { evaluationSummaryComponent } from './evaluation.summary';


const evaluationComponent: angular.IComponentOptions = {
  template: require('./evaluation.html'),
  controller: EvaluationController,
  controllerAs: 'evaluation'
};

export const evaluationModule = 'evaluation';

angular.module(evaluationModule, [])
  .component('evaluationPaste', evaluationPasteComponent)
  .component('evaluationParse', evaluationParseComponent)
  .component('evaluationSummary', evaluationSummaryComponent)
  .component('evaluation', evaluationComponent);
```

When I do it like this, I don't see "paste component" text.

But if I do it with custom element it works.

```
<evaluation-paste ng-show="evaluation.step == 'paste'"></evaluation-paste>
```

But I need DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [comparison table between directives and components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition), components have only the element restriction. You should use directive with `restrict: 'A'` (attribute) instead of component.